# How to copy a UCHAR string in WCHAR string in C Windows Kernel Driver

Tags: c, string, windows, driver, wdm

I'm having troubles in this piece of code, i'm trying to save the retrieved list of loaded system modules in a struct array defined as:

```
typedef struct _DRIVER_INFO {  
    PVOID MappedBase;     
    PVOID ImageBase;     
    ULONG ImageSize;     
    WCHAR ModuleName[MAXIMUM_FILENAME_LENGTH];     
    WCHAR FullPathName[MAXIMUM_FILENAME_LENGTH]; 
} DRIVER_INFO;
```

and the source of data is a struct defined as:

```
typedef struct _SYSTEM_MODULE_INFORMATION {
    HANDLE Section;     
    PVOID MappedBase;     
    PVOID ImageBase;     
    ULONG ImageSize;     
    ULONG Flags;     
    USHORT LoadOrderIndex;     
    USHORT InitOrderIndex;     
    USHORT LoadCount;     
    USHORT OffsetToFileName;     
    UCHAR FullPathName[MAXIMUM_FILENAME_LENGTH]; 
} SYSTEM_MODULE_INFORMATION, * PSYSTEM_MODULE_INFORMATION;
```

This is the code i can't complete, I've tried different functions to copy a string defined in wdm.h.
I have to copy a UCHAR string in WCHAR (even UNICODE_STRING would be fine)

```
for (ULONG i = 0; i < moduleList->NumberOfModules; i++)
{
    PRTL_PROCESS_MODULE_INFORMATION module = (PRTL_PROCESS_MODULE_INFORMATION)&moduleList->Modules[i];
    DRIVER_INFO driverInfo;
    driverInfo.MappedBase = module->MappedBase;
    driverInfo.ImageBase = module->ImageBase;
    driverInfo.ImageSize = module->ImageSize;
    
    //Here i have to copy module.FullPathName in driverInfo.FullPathName
    //and module.FullPathName + module.OffsetToFileName in driverInfo.ModuleName
    
    systemDrivers[i] = driverInfo;
    DebugMessage("Driver Path: %s\n", driverInfo.FullPathName);
}
```

**EDIT 1**:

With just the first `RtlAnsiStringToUnicodeString` it works, but if I add the second one it dies and reports "attempted write to read only location", what am I missing?

```
for (ULONG i = 0; i < moduleList->NumberOfModules; i++)
{
    PRTL_PROCESS_MODULE_INFORMATION module = (PRTL_PROCESS_MODULE_INFORMATION)&moduleList->Modules[i];
    DRIVER_INFO driverInfo;
    PCSTR moduleName = (PCSTR)(module->FullPathName + module->OffsetToFileName);
    PCSTR fullPathName = (PCSTR)(module->FullPathName);
    DebugMessage("Driver Name: %s, Driver Path: %s\n", moduleName, fullPathName);
    //driverInfo.MappedBase = module->MappedBase;
    //driverInfo.ImageBase = module->ImageBase;
    //driverInfo.ImageSize = module->ImageSize;

    RtlAnsiStringToUnicodeString(&driverInfo.ModuleName, (PCANSI_STRING)&moduleName, TRUE);
    RtlAnsiStringToUnicodeString(&driverInfo.FullPathName, (PCANSI_STRING)&fullPathName, TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Simple way would be to run through the arrays and copy element-by-element from the `UCHAR` to the `WCHAR`. I *think* that will not break any encodings but not 100% sure. (Note, the `memcpy` in my earlier comment won't work, of course!)

Comment: There is [`RtlAnsiStringToUnicodeString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-rtlansistringtounicodestring). You'll need to handle the null termination yourself.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/ProcessManager.cs,1179

Comment: @AdrianMole "I think that will not break any encodings but not 100% sure." I think it's the opposite. I think there is no encoding where that works. Is there any encoding that maps byte 0x80 to U+0080?

Comment: @RaymondChen Hmm. Now you have me scratching my head. When the source is *signed* `char`, I'd tend to agree with you. But, in this case, the source is `UCHAR`. Not sure how that works on Windows. A quick test shows that 0x80 is `Ç` when converted to either a `char` or a `wchar_t` on the default Windows console.

Comment: @AdrianMole If you look at a Unicode table, you'll see that U+0080 is "padding character" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement it may print as € but it is not the Euro symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it in this way, thank you all.

```
for (ULONG i = 0; i < moduleList->NumberOfModules; i++)
{
    PRTL_PROCESS_MODULE_INFORMATION module = (PRTL_PROCESS_MODULE_INFORMATION)&moduleList->Modules[i];
    PCSTR moduleName = (PCSTR)(module->FullPathName + module->OffsetToFileName);
    ANSI_STRING ansiModuleName;
    RtlInitAnsiString(&ansiModuleName, moduleName);
    PCSTR fullPathName = (PCSTR)(module->FullPathName);
    ANSI_STRING ansiFullPathName;
    RtlInitAnsiString(&ansiFullPathName, fullPathName);
    systemDrivers[i].MappedBase = module->MappedBase;
    systemDrivers[i].ImageBase = module->ImageBase;
    systemDrivers[i].ImageSize = module->ImageSize;
    RtlAnsiStringToUnicodeString(&systemDrivers[i].ModuleName, &ansiModuleName, TRUE);
    RtlAnsiStringToUnicodeString(&systemDrivers[i].FullPathName, &ansiFullPathName, TRUE);
}
```